RSI calculation for MQL4 and Pinescript Different?
When converting a indicator from MQL4 to Pinescript, I was able to get it to work, but the values displayed in pinescript and the original MT4 are quite different. I am tying to display the composite RSI values (2 and 9) for a security on a lower timeframe, with reference to 2 higher timeframes (the 15M and 1H).
The following is the MQL Code:
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 1
#property indicator_color1  Crimson
#property indicator_width1  2
#property indicator_level1  50

extern int Tframe1=15;
extern int Tframe2=60;
extern int NumBars=2000;

double Crsi[];
double four2, four9, day2, day9;
double RSItot;
int RSInum;
int fouri, dayi, i;

int init()
{
   IndicatorBuffers(1);
   SetIndexBuffer(0,Crsi); SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE); 
   
   return(0);
}
int deinit() { return(0); }


int start()
{

   for ( i=NumBars; i>=0; i--)
   {
       fouri = iBarShift(Symbol(), Tframe1, Time[i], false); 
       dayi = iBarShift(Symbol(), Tframe2, Time[i], false);
      
      RSInum=0;  RSItot=0;
      
      if(Tframe1>0){
         four2 = iRSI(NULL,Tframe1,2,PRICE_CLOSE,fouri);   
         four9 = iRSI(NULL,Tframe1,9,PRICE_CLOSE,fouri); 
        
        RSInum=RSInum+2;  RSItot=RSItot+four2+four9;
        }  
      if(Tframe2>0){
         day2 = iRSI(NULL,Tframe2,2,PRICE_CLOSE,dayi);   
         day9 = iRSI(NULL,Tframe2,9,PRICE_CLOSE,dayi); 
        
        RSInum=RSInum+2;  RSItot=RSItot+day2+day9;
        }  

         Crsi[i]=RSItot/RSInum;
   }     

   return(0);
}  



and this is my pinescript code:
indicator(title="CRSI")

rsiM15two = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15" , ta.rsi(close, 2)[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])
rsiH1two = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.rsi(close, 2)[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])

rsiM15nine = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", ta.rsi(close, 9)[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])
rsiH1nine = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.rsi(close, 9)[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])

rsitwo = rsiM15two + rsiH1two 
rsinine = rsiM15nine + rsiH1nine 

compositeRSI = (rsitwo+rsinine)/4

plot(compositeRSI, "CompositeRSI", style=plot.style_line, color = color.red)



It should produce the same (or similar results), but there is quite a difference in the output. Is there a difference in the way RSI values are computed?
